# Php echo three different css formats

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am trying to add three different css formats to data pulled from MySQL database.
I have formatted the first row fine but I cant get the other two working at all,
any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
//run the query
$loop = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee")
   or die (mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($loop))
{
  echo "<p style='color:#0000ff; font-size:22px'>".$row  ['employee_name']."</p>" "<p style='color:#00000f; font-size:32px'>".$row['employee_id'] . "</p>" "<p style='color:#000000; font-size:42px'>". $row['employee_contact'] . " </p>"  . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: You shouldn’t be using inline styles here anyway. Give those elements a class, and format them via that class through your stylesheet. (And btw., using paragraph elements doesn’t make the most sense here either.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quotes are not balanced. Try this :

```
echo "<p style='color:#0000ff; font-size:22px'>".$row  ['employee_name']."</p> <p style='color:#00000f; font-size:32px'>".$row['employee_id'] . "</p><p style='color:#000000; font-size:42px'>". $row['employee_contact'] . " </p> <br/>";
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an unecessary gap:

```
  $row['employee_id'] . "</p>" "<p style='color:#000000; font-size:42px'>"
                            ^^^^^
                             here
```

Either get rid of the quotes or add a concatenation operator.

```
  $row['employee_id'] . "</p> <p style='color:#000000; font-size:42px'>"
```

Comment: Graphic illustration works so very well when outlining where the errors are done. It must be the "artist" in you ;-)